# Função para calcular calorias

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

> Crie uma função chamada `caloriasDeTrote()`, que recebe por parâmetro o número de voltas representado por um valor numérico e retorne a quantidade de calorias que será consumida.

Por exemplo: ao chamar a função `caloriasDeTrote(2)`

Deveria devolver 15 onde 5 calorias são da primeira volta (5 * 1) mais 10 calorias da segunda (5 * 2).

Sendo assim eu tentei criar a seguinte função:

```js
  function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) { 
 var calorias = 0; 
 for (var i = 0; i < numeroDeVoltas; i++) {  
  calorias = 5 * numeroDeVoltas

 } 
return calorias; 
}

caloriasDeTrote(2)
```

Só que o resultado não sai como esperado, pois nesse exemplo, ao chamar a função `caloriasDeTrote(2)`, deveria retornar o número 15 e não 10.

Pois `caloriasDeTrote(1)` é igual a 5 (5 * 1) e `caloriasDeTrote(2)` é igual 10 (5* 2) então a função deveria somar os valores resultando em 15. Essa seria a lógica em diante.

Comment: faça `calorias += 5 * i;` ou então transforme a função numa PG: `function caloriasDeTrote(voltas) { return (voltas == 1)? 5 : 5 + 5 * voltas;}`

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pelo retorno mas não funcionou, usei a seguinte função:

function caloriasDeTrote(voltas) 
{ return (voltas == 1)? 5 : 5 + 5 * voltas}

porém quando chamo a função com o valor 3 caloriasDeTrote(3) ela retorna 20 e deveria retornar 30, pois seria (5*1) = 5 + (5*2) = 10 + (5*3) = 15 , sendo assim, 5+10+15 = 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um dos erros é que não está acumulando as calorias de cada volta. Outro é que neste caso é um dos raros laços que devem começar do 1 e não do 0 e encerrar quando chega na volta desejada (até dá para fazer do jeito tradicional, mas precisa fazer conta, é pior). E o último erro é que está multiplicando sempre pelo número de volta e não pela volta atual antes de acumular.

```js
function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) { 
    var calorias = 0; 
    for (var i = 1; i <= numeroDeVoltas; i++) calorias += 5 * i;
    return calorias; 
}
console.log(caloriasDeTrote(2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Calories.js).

Acho que dá pra otimizar mais, mas assim resolve o problema sem inventar demais.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo e consegui entender onde estava o erro. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) {
  var quantidadeDeCalorias = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= numeroDeVoltas; i++){
    quantidadeDeCalorias += 5 * i;
  }

  return quantidadeDeCalorias;
}
```